# How to use a {{key}} from Django in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django, dictionary

Javascript cannot find element by id using {{key}}

How can I access the {{key}} in my script?

Script

```
window.onload = jQuery(function ($) {
    var duration = document.getElementById("#timerseconds{{key}}").value;
    duration = 10800 - duration;
    display = $("#counter{{key}}");
    startTimer(duration, display);
});
```

HTML / DJANGO

```
{% for key, value in list_cooking.items %}

 <li class="list-group-item">
 <p>{{key}}</p>
 <br></br>
 <p>Seconds:</p><p id='counter{{key}}'>00</p>
 <input id="timerseconds{{key}}" type="hidden" value="{{value}}">
 </li>
```

Console

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'value' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:78)
```

Rendered HTML

```
<li class="list-group-item">
   <p>Beef</p>
   <br>
   <p>Seconds:</p>
   <p id="#counterBeef">00</p>
   <input id="timersecondsBeef" type="hidden" value="5417">
</li>
```

VIEW

```
time_since = AddCooking.objects.raw("select * from heatcook_addcooking where time_start > now() - interval '180 minutes'")

for item in time_since:
        list_cooking[item.foodfk.name] = (int((time_now - item.time_start).total_seconds()))
```

Solution:
Use  inside the for loop

```
{% for key, value in list_cooking.items %}
   <script>Script here</script>
   <li class="list-group-item">
   <p>{{key}}</p>
   <br></br>
   <p>Seconds:</p><p id='counter{{key}}'>00</p>
   <input id="timerseconds{{key}}" type="hidden" value="{{value}}">
   </li>
```

Comment: Your JS isn't working because `{{key}}` is not defined outside the for-loop. You'll rather have to select elements using class names, rather than IDs.

Comment: Using the <script> inside the loop I could access {{key}}
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to also iterate over the JavaScript code in the template:

```
{% for key, value in list_cooking.items %}
     <li class="list-group-item">
     <p>{{key}}</p>
     <br></br>
     <p>Seconds:</p><p id='counter{{key}}'>00</p>
     <input id="timerseconds{{key}}" type="hidden" value="{{value}}">
     </li>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload = jQuery(function ($) {
            var duration = $("#timerseconds{{key}}").val();
            duration = 10800 - duration;
            display = $("#counter{{key}}");
            startTimer(duration, display);
        });
    </script>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Still get null
var duration = document.getElementById("#timerseconds{{key}}").value;

Comment: I updated it to use JQuery instead. see if that works.

Comment: If that still doesn't work, please send the source of the rendered HTML page to ensure your key and value are rendering properly. Also post how you are creating the cooking_list object.

Comment: The JQuery is working.
With the script inside the loop i could get {{key}}

Thanks Michael!